# Counting certain rows in PowerBI

Tags: count, powerbi, xls

I never used PowerBI and this is a trivial problem in pandas, but I don`t know how this works here.

I have an Excel that contains a lot of columns, some of which problematic because it throws me an error when I am trying to load it in PowerBI. The columns that interest me are just (out of 20 columns):

```
Object                Status
444444441             X
444444442
444444443             X
444444444             X
444444445
```

I just want to count the Objects whose Status is marked, and display them in a diagram. Do I need to convert the values of Status into 0 and 1`s, so bool instead of text, and then count them? I tried to convert it automatically and it doesn`t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully sure about the solution you strive for, but here, two primitive ones:

- Calculate a measure that gives you the number of objects with status "X":

  `Count1 = COUNTAX(FILTER(data, data[Status]="X"), data[Object])`

  which would give you e.g.

  [image]
- Add the plot, mark it and chose "Status is X" in the filter menue:

  [image]

  which gives you the following:

  [image]

  where `Count2 = count(data[Object])`

Hope that does help!